# Gradle: calling jar task

Tags: gradle

I want to implement a task which builds a jar. Another distribution task should call the jar task and the jar should output where the jar was generated. However the jar task is not called from mydist and the path printed is not created.

```
task myjar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName "my.jar"
    destinationDir = distribution_dir
    println 'jar ' + archiveName + ' created in ' + destinationDir
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainclass
    }
    with jar
}

task mydist << {
    myjar.execute()
}
```

Comment: Tasks should never be executed manually. The flow you try to implement is unclear. Could you please put it a wider context?

Comment: my question is why execute does not work. the idea is to separate tasks and call the independently like functions

Comment: Tasks are *not* functions and should be called that way. `execute` probably does not work because there's no action added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "myjar" to execute before "mydist", then after the declaration of "mydist", do this:

```
mydist.dependsOn myjar
```